# react-datepicker includeTimes option

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I want two react-datepicker with one showing start time and another showing end time. In end-time picker, I want to disable the times before the time selected in from time picker.

So if I select from time as 8:00pm, then all the time before 8:00pm shuld be disabled

for End time picker,i am doing the following

```
<DatePicker
     selected={this.state.endTime}
     onChange={this.changeEndTime}
     showTimeSelect
     showTimeSelectOnly
     timeIntervals={30}
     timeCaption="Time"
     includeTimes={[
         setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 17),
         setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 30), 18),
         setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 30), 19),
         setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 30), 17)
     ]}
     className={classes.timer}
     dateFormat="h:mm aa"
 />
```

But, all the times are disabled in the drop down of time picker..Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not instead use the `minTime` and `maxTime` properties to manipulate what times are enabled/disabled?

In other words, when you select a value like 2:00pm in the **FROM TIME** date picker, the **TO TIME** date picker `minTime` property you will set to 2:30pm.

This can be handled with the FROM TIME `onChange` event.  You can create a state variable where you store minimum time, and update that state in the FROM TIME `onChange` event.  Then every time the value changes the `minTime` property on the TO TIME will change.

See their documentation with `minTime` and `maxTime`: https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-specific-time-range

Comment: Thanks for the response.....I tried the following                                                                                                        
    <DatePicker
          showTimeSelect
           showTimeSelectOnly
           minTime={setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 5)}
           maxTime={setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 20)}
     />                                                                               but everything in the dropdown is coming disabled and it is showing all the dates(irrespective of min and max dates)

Answer (score 0):

My DatePicker code

```
<DatePicker
    selected={this.state.endTime}
    onChange={this.changeEndTime}
    showTimeSelect
    showTimeSelectOnly
    timeIntervals={30}
    timeCaption="Time"
    className={classes.timer}
    dateFormat="h:mm aa"
    minTime={this.endMinDate}
    maxTime={setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 30), 23)}
/>
```

*endMinDate I am calculating in a function

setHours and setMinutes was not working properly(setHours() was somehow setting minutes to the date)

initailly I was importing as follows

```
import setHours from "date-fns/setMinutes";
import setMinutes from "date-fns/setMinutes";
```

then, I did the following change

```
import {setSeconds, setMinutes} from "date-fns";
```

So the code is now working, although I am still not sure, how imports are making a difference

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  What seems to be going on with your imports is a concept called "tree shaking", where webpack is causing the bundling to pull only what is needed, instead of all of date-fns.  Here are some links:  https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.7/docs/ECMAScript-Modules, https://bitsofco.de/what-is-tree-shaking/